# Building a Github library project locally in Android Studio 2

Tags: android, android-studio

Like many a newbie I've been blindly clicking away in Android Studio 2 stumbling my way through building an app. Most of it just works so I've not really got my head into gradle.

Any road up, I've wanted to link into Strava and discovered that there were a couple of guys who had done the heavy lifting but on using a specific project, at the vital point of getting the data there is a coding problem. I thought the best approach would be to solve the problem and feedback.

So I downloaded the GitHub project in a zip and tried to do a standalone build and then things just didn't work. I think the basic problem is a) I don't know what I'm doing, and b) presumably the build on GitHub was done using different tools that are not set up for Android Studio.

**So given that there is a working project on GitHub (specifically https://github.com/SweetzpotAS/StravaZpot-Android ) what are the dummy steps for getting that project to build locally in AS 2?**

The problems I had are that on trying to open the project picking up the gradle file (couldn't find anything else to open in the root directory, the build didn't want to work - complaints about mixed projects. I stripped out the testing app and just tried to build the lib, but I didn't get a working lib in the output directory, just 2 25k stub aar files. Ideally I want to have that as a standalone project to build a local lib and then use that lib in my project (which I reckon is within my abilities!). Run out of Google search ideas!

Comment: If you scroll all the way to the bottom of the readme there, you can see that it's in JCenter, so there is no need to download anything manually (Gradle will do it for you).  Just add this to your dependencies in your app level gradle: `compile 'com.sweetzpot.stravazpot:lib:1.0.0-beta1'`

Comment: Sorry, I know how to use GitHub and had used the readme as it draws in lots of stuff. I have had it working I guess that the idea is to fork it, patch it on GitHub and then when you are done let it die a dignified death. However, in principle, that whole chunk of code should be buildable on my PC.